# Unity Android plugin - package rename issue

Tags: android, java-native-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a simple plugin to Unity Android, that displays an image from the web.
I've created a Jar using my Java files, and loaded it (in a blank Unity sample application) using AndroidJavaClass.

All worked fine, but then I've wanted to rename my Java package.
From now on - I can't see the image. The plugin doesn't even trying to access it.

I've changed the package name in the Java files, and also in the AndroidManifest.xml and in the CS file that's calling it.
The Jar compiles successfully, the application runs on the device, but... nothing.

I've also created a new application that uses the plugin with his new name, but no success.

What have I done wrong?
Or - what can I do to make it work?

Thanks,
Keren

Comment: Are you sure you copied over the new Jar file? I made this mistake several times..

Answer (score 1):

Why would you code a plug-in to display a web image ?
Just use unity native `WWW` call, then put the result in a texture.

[Look at the unity docs](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html).